# Why does throw itself cause an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a piece of C++ program that can not be simpler

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void throwE(){
  throw "ERROR";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  try{
    throwE();

  } catch(const std::string& msg){
    cerr << msg << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But it raises an exception when run:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens, why is the exception not caught?

Comment: wait...why is that not an std::string??

Comment: It *can* be simpler. You could catch what you're throwing (or throw what your catching; the choice is yours).

Comment: @MatthewYang Since when `"ERROR"` ever formed a `std::string`? It's a `const char*` literal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, it's a `const char [6]` literal.

Comment: @Angew Although, poking around, it seems the throw is considered to throw a `const char*` (I tried catching `const char (&msg)[6]` with no luck :-))

Comment: @juanchopanza 15.1/3: The type of the exception object is adjusted from `T[]` to `T*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't throwing an `std::string`, but a nul terminated string (the type of `"ERROR" is really const char[6]`, and the `throw` expression decays that to `const char*`.). So you don't catch the exception. If you change `throwE` to throw an `std::string`, it works as expected:

```
void throwE(){
  throw std::string("ERROR");
}
```

Alternatively, catch a `const char*`, which matches the type of the exception thrown after the `const char[6]` decays to `const char*`:

```
} catch(const char* msg){
  cerr << msg << endl;
}
```

Output:

> ERROR

Comment: In C++14 you can write `"ERROR"s` to get a literal of type `std::string`.